# Папка 'Недавние документы' и 'Недавние места'

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-7, реестр, windows-server

Есть компьютер с ОС Windows 7.

По пути (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent) находится папка ''Недавние документы''. В ней отображается список, недавно открытых файлов и папок на компьютере. Есть ещё по пути (C:\Users\User\Links) папка ''Недавние места'' в ней показаны недавно открытые папки.

**Вопрос.** Можно ли как-то через реестр увеличить список, чтобы в этой папке отобразились действия за 2-3 месяца?

---

P. S. Если это не осуществимо через реестр-windows, подскажите, пожалуйста, решения или сторонние ПО для этого.

---

На этих сайтах показано как это сделать, только для меню.

http://www.hz0.ru/?p=680

http://www.winblog.ru/quicktip/1147767670-10101101.html

https://howto.mediadoma.com/kak-uvelichit-kolichestvo-jelementov-spiska-perehodov-v-windows-11/

https://ru.technology-news-hub.com/4071-how-to-increase-the-number-of-jump-list-items-in-windows-10

---

А я ищу как это можно сделать для папки 'Недавние документы' и 'Недавние места'.

P.S. Может кто-нибудь подскажет как это сделать только для папок? ОС Windows 7

Comment: Может кто нибудь помочь с этим?

Comment: Реестр лучше не трогать, а то если где-нибудь ошибешься, винда накроется. Управлять списком недавних файлов можно, например, с помощью программ CCleaner и RecentX.